# Synthesis of 1-ethylcyclohexane-1,2-diol from cyclohexylethene

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

Here's my synthesis:

1. HBr
2. NaEtO
3. OsO4/NMO

But the problem is that for step 2, there are 3 possible alkene locations, with all of them having 3 substituents, so I would have all 3 forming (although 2 of them would result in the same thing). So I checked my professor's solution, but he used HBr twice. However, wouldn't the first HBr result in a hydride shift, making the 2nd HBr unnecessary?

Either way, this solution also allows the formation of alkene in 3 sites, just like my solution. Is that allowed?

This is my prof's solution:
[image]

Comment: A hydride shift in the first HBr reaction is certainly possible, but you will likely get a mixture of positional isomers of brominated products